# Firebase Token is not generated in some devices

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging, runtime-error

i am using push notification in my project and setup FirebaseMessagingService as required. This works fine for most of the devices. In some cases the Firebase Token is not generated. In such cases i used below code to fetch the Firebase Token again.

```
FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().getToken().addOnSuccessListener(token -> {
            
        }).addOnFailureListener(e -> {
            
        }).addOnCanceledListener(() -> {
            
        }).addOnCompleteListener(task ->{
            String token = task.getResult();
            
        });
```

The error is thrown in the 'addOnCompleteListener' method.

Project Settings

- compileSdkVersion 29
- buildToolsVersion "29.0.3"
- minSdkVersion 19
- targetSdkVersion 29
- firebase-config:19.2.0
- firebase-messaging:21.0.1

some failing devices

1. Samsung Galaxy M31
2. Samsung Galaxy J6
3. Moto E Plus
4. Redmi 6A

The initial crashlystics error report

> Fatal Exception: com.google.android.gms.tasks.RuntimeExecutionException
> java.io.IOException: SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE
> com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzu.getResult
> (com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks@@17.1.0:15)
> com.truetech.whatsup.redwhatsup.login.activity.EmailLoginActivity.lambda$updateToken$9$EmailLoginActivity
> (EmailLoginActivity.java:648)
> com.truetech.whatsup.redwhatsup.login.activity.-$$Lambda$EmailLoginActivity$kYn6jMOwll1UMuLxMbs8khArCVU.onComplete
> (Unknown Source:2) com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzj.run
> (com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks@@17.1.0:4)
> android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:938)
> android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:99)
> com.google.android.gms.internal.tasks.zzb.dispatchMessage
> (com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks@@17.1.0:6)
> android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:246)
> android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:8506)
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
> com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run
> (RuntimeInit.java:602) com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main
> (ZygoteInit.java:1139)

any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: In Emulator ,Make sure that you have signed-in google play service

Comment: @androidLearner The code is executed in real device. Also what do you mean by 'signed-in google play services'